# I need a clarification on a simple proof

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Can somebody explain to me how in Sangchul Lee answer here: [The set $\{\frac{\varphi(n)}n:n\in \Bbb N\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136634/the-set-frac-varphinnn-in-bbb-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) $|f(n_k) - f(n_{k-1})| < \epsilon$ implies for $f(n_k) \to 0$?

Comment: That implication is stated nowhere in the post.

Comment: The reason why $f(n_k)\to 0$ is that [the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes), which is equivalent to saying that $\prod\limits_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$ diverges to $0$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Thank you. Why did Sangchul Lee prove that $|f(n_k) - f(n_{k-1})| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Could you also say why  the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges $\Rightarrow$ $\prod\limits_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$?

Comment: $n_k$ actually depends both on $N$ and $k$, so we may rather call it $n^N_k$. $f(n^N_0)$ is, by definition, a number $\ge 1-\varepsilon$. Then you start decreasing to $0$ by at most $\varepsilon$ at each step. So any $x$ will be between $2$ of those points, and it will be at most $\varepsilon$ form each. Do it for all $\varepsilon$ and you obtain density.

Comment: The other thing is just an elementary property of [infinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had previously commented (Saucy O'Path confirms) there is no such implication.
On the other hand we can prove the result directly as follows:

I know it's a long shot, but, using the [Euler Product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula)
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{p_k^s}\right)=\frac1{\zeta(s)}$$
with $s=1$ 
and knowing that $\zeta(1)=\infty$ (this is the harmonic series) we obtain the result as,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(n_k)=\prod_{k=\color{red}{N}}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)$$
and the first terms (which we are missing) play no role in the product converging to $0$.